# Java variable function parameters

Tags: java, function, variables, parameters

How do you duplicate this feature in Java?

In C#, you could use the `params` keyword to specify variable parameter lists for functions.

How do you do that in Java?

Or do you have to resort to multiple overloads?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

C# code:

```
double Average(params double[] nums) {
  var sum = 0.0;
  foreach(var num in nums) 
    sum += num;
  return sum / nums.Length;
}
```

Equivalent Java code:

```
double average(double... nums) {
  double sum = 0.0;
  for(double num : nums) 
    sum += num;
  return sum / nums.length;
}
```

This feature is known as varargs. You can read more about it [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html).

Answer (score 3):

The parameters to **variadic functions** ("[varargs](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html)" in Java-speak) are exposed to the Java function body as an array.  The example from the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function#Variadic_functions_in_C.23.2C_VB.net.2C_and_Java) illustrates this perfectly:

```
public static void printSpaced(Object... objects) {
   for (Object o : objects)
     System.out.print(o + " ");
 }

 // Can be used to print:
 printSpaced(1, 2, "three");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `...`. For example:

```
public void foo(int... args) {
  for (int arg : args) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can use [varargs](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html). But this works only for `1.5` or newer versions.